# Can CopyFileEx be called from a secondary thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, file-copying

Is it possible and right to call CopyFileEx and CopyCallback/ProgressRoutine function (ProgressBar.Position will be synchronized)  from a thread?

Can I declare CopyCallback/ProgressRoutine function in a thread? I get Error: "Variable required" in CopyFileEx on @ProgressRoutine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course it's possible. The callback function will be called in the context of the thread that calls `CopyFileEx`. If you need to synchronize some UI commands, use Delphi's usual `TThread.Synchronize`, or whatever other inter-thread synchronization techniques you want.

The callback function cannot be a method of the thread class. It needs to match the signature dictated by the API, so it needs to be a standalone function. When you've declared it correctly, you won't need to use the `@` operator when you pass it to `CopyFileEx`.

```
function CopyProgressRoutine(TotalFileSize, TotalBytesTransferred: Int64;
  StreamSize, StreamBytesTransferred: Int64;
  dwStreamNumber, dwCallbackReason: DWord;
  hSourceFile, hDestinationFile: THandle;
  lpData: Pointer): DWord; stdcall;
```

You can give the callback function access to the associated thread object with the `lpData` parameter. Pass a reference to the thread object for that parameter when you call `CopyFileEx`:

```
procedure TCopyThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  CopyResult := CopyFileEx(CurrentName, NewName, CopyProgressRoutine, Self,
    @Cancel, CopyFlags);
  ...
end;
```

With access to the thread object, you can call methods on that object, including its own progress routine, so the following could constitute the entirety of the standalone function. It can delegate everything else back to a method of your object. Here I've assumed the method has all the same parameters as the standalone function, except that it omits the `lpData` parameter because that's going to be passed implicitly as the `Self` parameter.

```
function CopyProgressRoutine;
var
  CopyThread: TCopyThread;
begin
  CopyThread := lpData;
  Result := CopyThread.ProgressRoutine(TotalSize, TotalBytesTransferred,
    StreamSize, StreamBytesTransferred, dwStreamNumber,
    dwCallbackReason, hSourceFile, hDestinationFile);
end;
```

Comment: Setting `TProgressBar.Position` does not require `TThread.Synchronize` IMO. `TProgressBar.SetPosition` method never allocates control's handle and works through `SendMessage` call which switches thread context by itself.

Comment: Technically, @Serg, there's a race condition. `TProgressBar` checks `HandleAllocated` before reading the `Handle` property. If the handle was already allocated, but it gets destroyed before reading `Handle`, then the handle will be re-allocated in the wrong thread. That's unlikely to happen, so `TProgressBar` is probably safe. In general, though, UI updates should get synchronized with the UI thread.

Comment: Can I declare CopyCallback/ProgressRoutine function in a thread? I get Error: "Variable required" in CopyFileEx on @ProgressRoutine.

Comment: You could queue instead of fully-locked synchronizing with TThread.Synchronize, though.